# How do I connect arduino with android with bluetooth module?

Tags: android, arduino

I am a beginner programmer in Android and have experience with C++ too. I am trying to create an app that controls the switching on and off the lights with Arduino and a bluetooth module but can't figure out how to transfer data to the bluetooth module via android. I learned how to connect bluetooth module with android but I can't figure out how to send commands and what commands are supported. 
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think this is what you are looking for

http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino5.php